# Updating to android studio 2.0

Tags: android-studio, android-studio-2.0

My current Android Studio version in 1.3.2. I want to update to 2.0 stable build. Is there a way to do this automatically? When I go to Help->Check for Updates, is says a new version of Android Studio is available.

The options it gives me at the bottom are Download, Release Notes, Ignore This update, and Remind me later.

Hitting download does not download it, but rather takes me to the canary channel of android studio and it says beta there. I just want to update to 2.0 stable.

Why is android studio not updating itself for me?

Comment: You might just have to go here: https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html